# Error functions in python

Tags: python, function

When I run my program i am getting an error the name "student is not defined".

## ======================================================================

```
# Function  to Determine each student's average test score using NESTED WHILE LOOPS
def calculateStudentsAverageTestScore():
    global testNum, numStudents, student;  # make variables available for other functions/subtasks


# Get a student's test scores
print();
print("Student number", student);
print("-" * 50);

testNum = 1; #Initialize testNum lcv for the inner loop used to control the number of tests per student
while (testNum <= numTestScores): # test testNum

            #Check to make sure data is numeric
                while True:
                    try:
                        print("Test number", testNum, end = " ");
                        score = float(input(": "));
                    except ValueError:
                        print("Error: Invalid data - enter a numeric value!");
                        continue;
                    else:
                        break;
                    #end while loop
                    
              # Calculate the average test score for this student.
                average = total / numTestScores; 
                testNum = testNum + 1; # counts the number of tests per student (updates testNum lcv)
              # End caluclateStudentsAverageTestScore
```

Comment: _Where_ does the error happen? Don't make us wade through your 150 lines of code just to find the place where the error happens. Include the complete traceback in your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error suggests, the variable `student` has not been defined. I noticed that you are using the `student` variable in the `initializeVariables()` function.

The issue here is that the variables are just locally defined for that function. If you would like to use those variables outside the function as well, first initialize the variables outside the function, and then use global variables instead.

Read more about global and local variables [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html).